# where/how do I specify sql server file groups in visual studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I see that there is a drop down list box in  in the project properties to chose the default file group but PRIMARY seems my only choice

Where can I define other File groups?

Answer (score 1):

A Filegroup is a database object.  You need to add one to your project before you can put tables on it.

[image]